# Threads and file writing

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a java program which uses 20 threads. Every one of them write their results in a file called `output.txt`.

I always get a different number of lines in `output.txt`.

Can it be a problem with the synchronization of threads? Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: Well, this is not very clear how is your implementation. As my simple test case shows, I get constant lines of output with FileWriter with 20 threads. It may be necessary to add some implementation details. See my answer.

Answer (score 33):

> can it be a problem of synchronization of threads?

Yes.

> There's a way to handle this?

Yes, ensure that writes are serialized by synchronizing on a relevant mutex. Or alternately, have only **one** thread that actually outputs to the file, and have all of the other threads simply queue text to be written to a queue that the one writing thread draws from. (That way the 20 main threads don't block on I/O.)

Re the mutex: For instance, **if** they're all using the same `FileWriter` instance (or whatever), which I'll refer to as `fw`, then they could use it as a mutex:

```
synchronized (fw) {
    fw.write(...);
}
```

If they're each using their own `FileWriter` or whatever, find something else they all share to be the mutex.

But again, having a thread doing the I/O on behalf of the others is probably also a good way to go.

Comment: Could you  please be more specific on what would be the best approach for the one writer thread approach? E.g. maybe using a [single thread Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--) and just submitting the tasks to that `Executor`?

Answer (score 12):

I'd suggest you to organize it this way: One thread-consumer will consume all data and write it to the file. All worker threads will produce data to the consumer thread in synchronous way. Or with multiple threads file writing you can use some mutex or locks implementations.

Comment: +1 I was just adding this suggestion to my answer as you were writing yours. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you want any semblance of performance and ease of management, go with the producer-consumer queue and just one file-writer, as suggested by Alex and others.  Letting all the threads at the file with a mutex is just messy - every disk delay is transferred directly into your main app functionality, (with added contention).  This is especially unfunny with slow network drives that tend to go away without warning.

Answer (score 2):

If you can hold your file as a `FileOutputStream` you can lock it like this:

```
FileOutputStream file = ...
....
// Thread safe version.
void write(byte[] bytes) {
  try {
    boolean written = false;
    do {
      try {
        // Lock it!
        FileLock lock = file.getChannel().lock();
        try {
          // Write the bytes.
          file.write(bytes);
          written = true;
        } finally {
          // Release the lock.
          lock.release();
        }
      } catch ( OverlappingFileLockException ofle ) {
        try {
          // Wait a bit
          Thread.sleep(0);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
          throw new InterruptedIOException ("Interrupted waiting for a file lock.");
        }
      }
    } while (!written);
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    log.warn("Failed to lock " + fileName, ex);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is totally redundant given that `synchronized` exists.

Comment: @EJP - see [FileLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) - *the locks held on a file should be visible to all programs that have access to the file, regardless of the language in which those programs are written* - so, in theory, they *should* be better than `synchronized` but often aren't.

Comment: That doesn't make it non-redundant, or 'better than `synchronized` either. There is nothing about other processes or other languages in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should use synchronization in this case. Imagine that 2 threads (t1 and t2) open the file at the same time and start writing to it. The changes performed by the first thread are overwrited by the second thread because the second thread is the last to save the changes to the file. When a thread t1 is writing to the file, t2 must wait until t1 finishes it's task before it can open it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, without any implementation detail, it is hard to know, but as my test case shows, I always get 220 lines of output, i.e., constant number of lines, with `FileWriter`. Notice that no `synchronized` is used here.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
/**
 * Working example of synchonous, competitive writing to the same file.
 * @author WesternGun
 *
 */
public class ThreadCompete implements Runnable {
    private FileWriter writer;
    private int status;
    private int counter;
    private boolean stop;
    private String name;


    public ThreadCompete(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        status = 0;
        stop = false;
        // just open the file without appending, to clear content
        try {
            writer = new FileWriter(new File("test.txt"), true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i=0; i<20; i++) {
            new Thread(new ThreadCompete("Thread" + i)).start();
        }
    }

    private int generateRandom(int range) {
        return (int) (Math.random() * range);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!stop) {
            try {
                writer = new FileWriter(new File("test.txt"), true);
                if (status == 0) {
                    writer.write(this.name + ": Begin: " + counter);
                    writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
                    status ++;
                } else if (status == 1) {
                    writer.write(this.name + ": Now we have " + counter + " books!");
                    writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
                    counter++;
                    if (counter > 8) {
                        status = 2;
                    }

                } else if (status == 2) {
                    writer.write(this.name + ": End. " + counter);
                    writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
                    stop = true;
                }
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I understand (and test), there are two phases in this process:

- all threads in the pool all created and started, ready to grab the file;
- one of them grabs it, and **I guess it then internally locks it**, prevents other threads to get access, because I never see a line combined of contents that come from two threads. So when a thread is writing, others are waiting until it completes the line, and very likely, releases the file. **So, no race condition will happen.**
- the quickest of the others grabs the file and begins writing.

Well, it is just like a crowd waiting outside a bathroom, without queuing.....

So, if your implementation is different, show the code and we can help to break it down.

Comment: you can try adding sleep between two writer.write() lines. That way you might be able to see that it is not thread safe

Comment: This isn't truly a multi-threaded example as the for loop will call the threads serially. To truly simulate multi-threading one can add a timer to trigger the function call at a random intervals repeatedly to see collisions.